# If I want to allow empty to an otherwise numerical input field, do I have to save the input value as string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
I'd like to do something like:

durationScalar: number;

...

durationScalar: 1

...

this.setState({ durationScalar: valueAsNumber });

...

<input name="durationScalar" type="number" value={this.state.durationScalar} min="0"/>
```

But when I empty the input field I get:

```
Received NaN for the `value` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.
```

If I use:

```
this.setState({ durationScalar: value });
```

then I get typescript warnings instead.

```
Argument of type '{ durationScalar: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
```

I can do the following without errors:

```
durationScalar: string;

...

durationScalar: "1"

...

this.setState({ durationScalar: value });

...

<input name="durationScalar" type="number" value={this.state.durationScalar} min="0"/>
```

But I would prefer to not have to store the value as a string as it is not a string. What is a good approach here?

**Edited to answer how I initialize the state**

```
interface SoftwareLicenseCodesState {
    durationScalar: number;
}

this.state = {
    durationScalar: 1
};
```

**Edited**

I also want to add that in tsconfig

```
"strictNullChecks": true,
```

Comment: How do you initialize your state?

Comment: @devserkan: post is edited to answer your question at the bottom

Comment: I can't reproduce the same behavior. I think this is related to `typescript` right? Then, maybe @mariamelior's answer will help.

Comment: @devserkan: It is related to Typescript, yes

Answer (score 0):

that if you use this option

```
 durationScalar: number | null;
```

or

```
value={this.state.durationScalar || 0}
```

Comment: I believe then I cannot have empty in that field, an objective described in the question title